# How are Heroku dyno names ($DYNO) assigned?

Tags: heroku, worker, dyno

I'm interested in assigning different workloads to each worker of a particular type in Heroku. The workload is continuous rather than discrete so a work queue is not appropriate. I could coordinate work through a database or Zookeeper, but these bring complexity and reliability issues.

I know that Heroku dynos are assigned names like `worker.1` but I'm curious how these names are assigned and if I can rely on them to have certain properties. I'm only interested in the behavior for worker dynos since web preboot probably changes the behavior for web dynos.

Specifically,

- Is it possible for two dynos to have the same name/number at the same time (I assume not for worker processes since the previous one should be shutdown or have failed before a new one is started)
- If the `ps:scale` for my worker is `n`, can I rely on dyno names being `worker.1`, `worker.2` ... `worker.n` or would I sometimes get numbers outside `(1, n)`? If it is possible to get numbers outside `(1, n)` under what circumstances might it happen?

I'm hoping to create a configuration that maps worker numbers to work assignments so I would rely on worker numbers to be exactly 1 to n.